# Mysql Safe to delete .TMD file?

Tags: mysql

Long story short. I had a very large corrupt InnoDB table. Tried a number of things to rebuild/recover the table. (I was finally successful) However, one of the things I tried was building a new table with Myisam engine with force innodb reovery on, however there was another crash along the way and I'm left with a .TMD file for that table.

Just curious if I'm safe to delete this file? Table does not show up anywhere in the database, via show tables, drop table doesn't do anything. etc. At this point its just taking up disk space in my data directory.

Answer (score 11):

The .TMD file is an intermediate data file for a table that needs to recreate its data file.

So you can remove it because it's normally used as a temporarly file but you could rename the file and check what happens just in case.